# Is there any way to do real time voice communication via bluetooth on arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, arduino-leonardo

Is there any way to send and play voice between two arduino projects which has connected via blutooth modules.

1st device ( sender ) : has microphone and bluetooth module to send voice.

2nd device ( reciever ) : has bluetooth module and speaker to play that voice on real time.like an phone call.

Is this possible to do with arduino or any other microcontroller?
Thank you.

Comment: Why use a microcontroller when there are bluetooth modules that do that already?

Comment: You haven't specified, which bluetooth modules you have, but most likely you have the standard HC-05 or HC-06 modules. Then the answer is somewhat "no". You may get it to work, but it will be very hacky and low quality audio. These are not made for audio. There are bluetooth modules made for audio, which also use an audio protocol in bluetooth (in contrast to the HC-05/6 modules)

Comment: with an esp32 you get into plausibility, but not with an UNO.